# Framework/tooling suggestions for building an editor-presentation type site like slides.com?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, presentation, editor

I've been building `Electron` desktop apps for a few years and I have a "presentation tool" type app using `d3` which I'd like to explore moving online. An example is something like [slides.com](https://slides.com/) (a pretty nice frontend UI for [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/)). I'm comfortable with `Javascript`, using `node.js` modules and various frontend frameworks (e.g `Bootstrap`) but have almost no experience with browser-based development, networking, security or backend development.

I'm hoping someone can give me a healthy shove (as opinionated as you like).

My `Electron` presentation tool enables a user to create interactive timelines using graphic assets and video which they "import" from their local drive. The presentation sequencing data is stored as JSON.

I'd like to be able to

- have the desktop app be able to "publish" projects to the web for viewing
- have an online version of the tool

So there are lots of moving parts here in terms of creating and authenticating user accounts, the uploading of assets, the storing of the project JSON, etc. but I'm a bit lost about development frameworks (e.g `Express.js`, `Mongo.db`, etc.) and especially how I set up tooling to start working on this.

Let me know if more info is needed (or if this question isn't appropriate for this stack).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an opensource project that you might want to try:

https://deckdeckgo.com/